# My android app doesn't work with 3g, only works with WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I have an android app for news linked with a webservice. It only works on WiFi, when i use 4G or 3G the app "unfortunately stop"s!

I searched but didn't find any clues.

```
<!-- Internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- Internet -->
```

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Are you sure that the device is connected to the internet?

Comment: Can you attach your console logs when trying to connect using 3G?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because of DNS information for the domain name you need to be connected to so when the device switched to 3g or 4g that carrier was not able to properly connect.

check [this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154676/cant-use-mobile-network-3g-4g-only-wifi-works-android) for more details and please add your console logs which will helps a lot.